# Create custom chrome for a windows form in vb.net using Visual Basic 2008 express

Tags: vb.net, window-style

How do you create custom chrome for a windows form in vb.net using Visual Basic 2008 express? I want to basically scrap what they give and start fresh, is there any way to do so easily?

Comment: Chrome?  What do you mean by Chrome?  I cannot see what Goggle Chrome would have to do with this?

Comment: Chrome has nothing to do with the browser, The "chrome" of the window is basically the GUI, by stripping the chrome I remove, essentially, the window.

Comment: Usually called window's styles, decorations, frames, etc., at least in the Windows world.  (the Chrome tag is definitely for Goggle Chrome though, which is why I changed it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out eventually. In the properties window with the form itself chosen, FormBorderStyle from "Sizable" to "None" will remove all built in chrome, therefore leaving me to go make my own. Resizability and moving may be a bit tough as I will have to code that myself, but this is an easy way to strip the chrome.